# Как создать массив структур с n длинной

Tags: массивы, c++-cli

Доброго времени суток.
Я не очень-то знаю С++, но очень нужно написать одну библиотеку для использования в C#.
Не могу создать массив с длинной зависящей от другого массива.

*Ошибка: выражение должно иметь константное значение*

```
/////Класс  для get_param_value_bynames ///////////////
public ref class P_BYNAME_DATA
{
public:
    String^ PntName;         //имя точки
    String^ PrmName;         //имя параметра
    short   nPrmOffset;      //смещение параметра
    PARvalue*   pupvValue;   //(входной/выходной) значение пара-метра
    short nType;             //(входной / выходной) тип значения
    long    fStatus;         //состояние каждого до-ступа к значению
    P_BYNAME_DATA() {}
    P_BYNAME_DATA(String^ name) { PntName = name; }
    virtual ~P_BYNAME_DATA() {}
};

///Класс для обращения 
public ref class Hscnapi
{
private:
    static int status;

public:
    static int get_param_value_bynames(String ^Server, array<P_BYNAME_DATA^>^ prmdata)
    {           
        int len = prmdata->Length;
        PARAM_BYNAME_DATA rgprmbd[i]; //Ошибка: выражение должно иметь константное значение 
    }

}
```

По-моему надо создать указатель для определения размера массива или что-то иное. Но я не знаю как.

Comment: Плохо понимаю людей, минусующих что-либо без объяснений.

Comment: PARAM_BYNAME_DATA rgprmbd[i] - ругается верно, PARAM_BYNAME_DATA rgprmbd[5] - ругаться не будет. ИМХО, говоря в двух словах, как сделано у Вас - так делать вообще нельзя. Либо сформулируйте исходную задачу, что Вам нужно и тогда кто-то сможет Вам помочь, либо (мне кажется это правильнее) - почитайте про стандартные контейнеры с++.

Comment: Ну или просто про new или gcnew

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов мне нужно создать массив rgprmbd того же размера что и prmdata.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/111071/